# KSQL Join streams with condition on struct field

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform, ksqldb

I have two streams defined each from a topic on which JSON messages are published a bit like this:

```
{"payload": {"some_id": "123"}}
```

Their corresponding streams are defined like this:

```sql
CREATE STREAM mystream
  (payload STRUCT <someid varchar>)
WITH (kafka_topic='mytopic', value_format='JSON')
```

When I try to JOIN the two streams together:

```sql
SELECT
  s.payload->some_id,
  o.payload->other_id
FROM mystream s
LEFT JOIN otherstream o ON s.payload->some_id = o.payload->other_id;
```

I get the following error:

```
Invalid comparison expression 'S.PAYLOAD->SOME_ID' 
in join '(S.PAYLOAD->SOME_ID = O.PAYLOAD->OTHER_ID)'.
Joins must only contain a field comparison.
```

Is it not possible to join two streams based on a struct field? Do I first need to publish a stream that flattens each source stream before I can perform the JOIN?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct, this is not currently possible. Feel free to upvote the issue tracking it here: https://github.com/confluentinc/ksql/issues/4051

As you say, the workaround is to flatten it in another stream first and then join it.